# Spring constructor injection without configuration (annotations, XML, java config)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I have problem with constructor injection for component scanned beans. I have following service

```
public class SomeService implements ISomeService {
    private ISomeService2 someService2;
    public SomeService(ISomeService2 someService2) {
        this.someService2 = someService2;
    }
. . .
}
```

Then I have this configuration that perform component scanning:

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(
            basePackages = "base.backage",
            includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = ".*"))
    public class AppConfig { }
```

Then I try to resolve ISomeService:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    ISomeService someService1 = ctx.getBean(ISomeService.class);
```

This throws exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodException (it does not have default non arg constructor). I have ISomeService2 bean scanned and registered as well. I can simply fix it by adding @Autowired annotation to SomeService constructor.

Is there a way how to make constructor injection by default without use of annotations inside classes, XML or any explicit configuration on particular bean?

Comment: Nope. You have to tell spring in some way to use auto wiring for that annotation or specify the relations yourself. You could in xml specify to use default auto wiring by type but that will turn it on for everything.

Comment: Does ISomeService2 qualify as a Spring component?

Comment: Yes - ISomeService2 is Spring bean

Comment: @M.Deinum how can I set this default auto wiring by type? I'm going to use constructor injection everytime.

Comment: You have to include an xml file which contains `default-autowire="constructor"`. However I would strongly recommend against using that. I would suggest you simply add `@Autowired` to the constructors you want to use for auto wiring, this makes it a bit less magical.